# variable not showing in ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

variable is not showing in ejs template when I press submit for the form.
Below is the code for the template.

```
<%- include("./partials/header"); -%>
<h1>Formula One Weather App</h1>
<p><%= startingContent %></p>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <select name="City" id="">
        <option value="Melbourne">Austrialian</option>
        <option value="Manama">Bahrain</option>

    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Find Weather</button>
</form>
<p><%= main %></p>
```

The code is accessing a weather API and I print to the console it does not want show on the template.
The code to access the API is below.

```
const homeStartingContent = "This is a really cool site about formula 1 weather"

 const app = express();
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 app.use(express.static("public"));
let currentweather = ""

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get("/", function(req, res){

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.body.City)

     var city = req.body.City;
     var APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    // var options = {

    // }
    var url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${APP_ID}`
    request(url, function(err, response, body){
        //console.log(body);

        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        var main = data.weather[0].main;
        //var temp = data.main.temp
        console.log(main)
        //res.render('home', {currentweather: main});
        // let cityWeather = res.write(`<p>The current weather in ${city} 
        // is ${main}`)
    })
})
```

Basically I am trying to render the weather for the city chosen.  Not sure what I have done wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are `app.get` and `app.post` nested?

Comment: Yes they are nested. I think this shouldn’t be the case?

Comment: Yes. That won't work. After receiving a `GET /` the server will start listening for `POST /` and stay like that